# Git Branch, Rebase, Merge & Tags

Tags: git, github

[This is my forked repo](https://github.com/iceblu3710/linux-sunxi-xenomai)

It is a VERY large repo with a few hundred thousand commits and branched 20+ deep. Only the commits with tags that have (-r#) are ones for my hardware. I have a patch that I have applied to the sunxi-v3.4.24-r1 tag.

```
    git clone https://github.com/iceblu3710/linux-sunxi-xenomai
    git checkout sunxi-v3.4.24-r1
    git branch -t i-pipe-core-uminded
    git add .
    git commit
    git push origin/i-pipe-core-uminded
```

I then want to rebase that branch with the upstream kernel changes

```
    git for-each-ref --format '%(refname)' refs/tags
    NOTE: Any way to get the short hash of the commit with these tags?
```

That will list all of the tags for the repo, here is whats relevant to me:

```
    refs/tags/sunxi-v3.4.24-r2
    refs/tags/sunxi-v3.4.29-r0
```

How do I go about upstream rebasing my branch to each of those tags in a clean manner?

And my main problem is rebase needs a branch name or hash to work, it does not accept tags and currently I do not know how to find a tag hash other than `git log --all | grep "TAG"` which takes quite a while on this big of a repo.

Thanks!

EDIT - Also is their a way to make that sunxi-v3.4.24-r1 tag my repo master and discard ALL of the commits before it? I have tried to use programs like gitk and smartgit but the log is so bloody huge they run out of memory. I will never be merging downstream and only following the upstram branch that that tag is on. ??

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem to find the tag hash, you can use the following command:

```
git rev-parse TAG
```

This will show you the commit hash.

Comment: that's what I wanted, any way to combine is with above so`30f766a - sunxi-v3.4.12-r0` is the output?

Comment: git for-each-rgit cat-file --batch-check `ef --format '%(refname)' refs/tags/ | grep "$@"` I thought that was going to work as the part in backticks outouts a list of tags and --batch-check is suppose to accept a list from stdout.